# Validating symfony2 forms with extra fields

Tags: symfony

I'm working on a symfony2 backend for a backbone.js application. I have my model and form.

However, backbone.js sends some additional properties to the REST API when it's creating/updating a model and I'm struggling to get the form to validate.

How can I get a form in symfony2 to accept additional data, or how can I drop particular keys before binding data to a form?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get Symfony2 accept additional data, add the additional fields to your form builder, and set their `property_path` option to false:

Example:

```
$builder
    ->add('my_additional_field', 'checkbox', array(
        'mapped' => false,
    ));
```

You don't need to drop the keys before binding the data, they'll be ignored anyway.

Comment: +1 Quick note for >= 2.1: "New in version 2.1: Since 2.1, the mapped option has been added for this use-case."

http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/reference/forms/types/hidden.html#mapped

Comment: Maybe you should consider to update your answer adding for what version is valid.

Answer (score 64):

You should use option "allow_extra_fields".

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
        $resolver->setDefaults(
        array(
            'allow_extra_fields' => true
        )
    );
}
```

For symfony 2.8+ use configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) instead of setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)

Comment: allow_extra_fields will not be included in symfony until 2.6. This will be the right way to add extra fields. mapped = false would be the suggested way if you know the extra field names that will be submitted.

Comment: As 2.6 has now been marked as a stable release this should be marked as the correct answer. @user1432227

Comment: @krun you could also add the symfony 2.8/3.* example where it is: `configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)` instead of the setDefaultOptions function.

Comment: Does there any option where I can set 'llow_extra_fields' to rue for all my forms ? I mean some configuration inside my config file ..maybe ?

Answer (score 16):

property_path is now deprecated in sf 2.1, use "mapped" instead

```
$builder
    ->add("firstName", "text")
    ->add("lastName", "text")
    ->add("tac", "checkbox", array(
        "mapped" => false
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can listen for `FormEvents::BIND_CLIENT_DATA` (or `FormEvents::PRE_BIND` if you are using 2.1 dev) event listener and add/remove fields. See [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html) cookbook entry.