# How to avoid of writing back data from symfony form?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I want to create readonly hidden field. Now I have field that looks like this:

```
$builder
        ->add('question_category_id', HiddenType::class);
```

And entity has method:

```
public function getQuestionCategoryId() {
    return $this->getQuestion()->getQuestionCategory()->getId();
}
```

After saving I got following error:

> Neither the property "question_category_id" nor one of the methods "addQuestionCategoryId()"/"removeQuestionCategoryId()", "setQuestionCategoryId()", "questionCategoryId()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Entity\UnitQuestionAnswer".

I could add dummy method

```
public function setQuestionCategoryId($id) {
    return $this;
}
```

but it is not right way.

How to create readonly hidden field, or avoid of writing back data from from into entity?

Comment: What are you trying to do with a readonly hidden field?

Comment: @JaredFarrish, to arrange questions by categories in template.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating symfony2 forms with extra fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868859/validating-symfony2-forms-with-extra-fields)

Comment: @VincenzoPetrucci, with mapped false it does not read data from entity.

Comment: @sectus: From the doc "If you wish the field to be ignored when reading or writing to the object, you can set the mapped option to false.". You can try also to add allow_extra_fields option to the form

Comment: S2.8 has a read_only attribute which would do what you want but it has been removed in 3.0.  disabled should work.  Just be aware that the value itself will not actually be submitted http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#disabled so if you are doing anything funky with the posted data then that could be a problem.  I suppose it's possible to fool around with the internals but that would be more trouble than it is worth.  So add a fake set method and move on.

Comment: @Cerad, `disabled` works for me. You could post this comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S2.8 has a read_only attribute which would do what you want but it has been removed in 3.0.

The disabled attribute should work. Just be aware that the value itself will not actually be submitted symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/… so if you are doing anything funky with the posted data then that could be a problem.

I suppose it's possible to fool around with the internals but that would be more trouble than it is worth.

Personally, given that my get method was added just for the form, I would just add a corresponding set method and move on.

Comment: @RyanVincent, yes, client could change disabled fields values, but disabled values does not send back to the server. And this value will be used only for visualization of the form using custom template.

Comment: @sectus - just be aware that the user could un-disable it and post the value which in turn would trigger the set not found message.  If the client does not actually need the value then don't send it.  Your twig template can pull it from the data object.